# Adding Intersect to a query if list isnt null

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to make a LINQ query to query my entity framework. What I need to do is add to the query I am building if certain elements are true.

I start off with

```
IQueryable<Jobs> GetJobs(list<string> staff, list<string> clients
{
var query = dbContext.Jobs.Where(a=> (a.JobName.Contains("New Job"));
```

I need to add the query if the lists are populated

```
if (staff.Count > 0) {
    query = query.where(a=>staff.Contains(a.staff));
}

if (client.Count > 0) {
    query = query.where(a => a.Clients.select(b=>b.Name).Intersect(client).Any();
```

Staff are a 1:1 relationship, and clients are many to many.

The query works if I only include staff, or clients, but when I have both it always returns 0.

Comment: Both of your extra conditions are combined with *and*.  Are you sure, when you look at the resulting sets individually, that they have at least one result element in common?

Comment: yes when both staff list and client list are populated the query should only return when both are true

Comment: Yes... but do you actually see at lease one record in the staff-only query that also appears in the client-only query?

Comment: yes when I do select * from jobs where id in (select spprojob_id from spproclientsjobs jobs whre spproclient_id=1) and jobname like ... and staff = ... it returns results

Comment: Name one result that is present in *both* queries.

Comment: yes, its just a typo.. and I didn't use my real code, but there are definitely records that meet both critera

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a set of jobs, that

- have a `JobName` like "New Job" and
- have a `Staff` property present in the given `staff` list and
- have at least one client from the given `clients` list

then, this should work.

```
IQueryable<Jobs> GetJobs(list<string> staff, list<string> clients)
{
    var query = dbContext.Jobs.Where(x => x.JobName.Contains("New Job"));

    if (staff != null && staff.Count > 0)
        query = query.Where(x => staff.Contains(x.Staff));

    if (clients != null && clients.Count > 0)
        query = query.Where(x => x.Clients.Any(c => clients.Contains(c.Name)));

    return query;
}
```